# In React, how does a child component call a function, which executes in the context of it's parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand this code, from the official react documentation:

https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/WZpxpz?editors=0010

```
class TemperatureInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onTemperatureChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const temperature = this.props.temperature;
    const scale = this.props.scale;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature in {scaleNames[scale]}:</legend>
        <input value={temperature}
               onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}

class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCelsiusChange = this.handleCelsiusChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFahrenheitChange = this.handleFahrenheitChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {temperature: '', scale: 'c'};
  }

  handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature});
  }

  handleFahrenheitChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'f', temperature});
  }

  render() {
    const scale = this.state.scale;
    const temperature = this.state.temperature;
    const celsius = scale === 'f' ? tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius) : temperature;
    const fahrenheit = scale === 'c' ? tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit) : temperature;

    return (
      <div>
        <TemperatureInput
          scale="c"
          temperature={celsius}
          onTemperatureChange={this.handleCelsiusChange} />
        <TemperatureInput
          scale="f"
          temperature={fahrenheit}
          onTemperatureChange={this.handleFahrenheitChange} />
        <BoilingVerdict
          celsius={parseFloat(celsius)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

On input change, we call `this.props.onTemperatureChange(e.target.value)`.

How does this function call execute in the context of the parent component?

What would be the equivalent behavior in plain JavaScript?

Is it just so, that when we pass down the parent component's function inside props, that function (i.e. `handleCelsiusChange`) is bound to the parent (`(this.handleCelsiusChange.bind(this)`), and no matter where we execute it, it is still going to make changes in it's own context?

Please correct me, if I am inaccurate in my description.

Comment: Yes you are correct regarding `this.handleCelsiusChange.bind(this)`. You'll get more idea if you'll react this blog article.
https://tylermcginnis.com/this-keyword-call-apply-bind-javascript/

> and more on 'this' keyword, bind, apply and call methods.

Comment: Yes `(this.handleCelsiusChange.bind(this)` will bind the function to `this`, which is parent component in your case  You can also read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are understanding it the right way as pointed out by `@Farhan Tahir` and `@Harsh kurra`. Probably they have answered your question regarding working of React and event propagation to parent. So, I'll talk about the second part — doing it in plain JavaScript.

I have implemented a simple example in Vanilla JS using the Constructor pattern. See the code below to understand.

```js
// Writing Constructors for Parent and Child.
function Parent(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.changeName = function(newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    };
}

function Child(changeName) {
    this.changeName = changeName;
}


// Creating instances and testing.

let p1 = new Parent('foo');
console.log(p1.name); // It will print 'foo'.

// Pass it to child and bind.
let c1 = new Child(p1.changeName.bind(p1));
c1.changeName('bar');

console.log(p1.name); // It will print 'bar'.
```

That's what happens behind the scene. React has further implementation on top of to reflect the changes in your component and other stuff.